# NOSQL - Understanding how to architect my tables in comparison to SQL

Tags: mongodb, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

In the SQL world, if I wanted to create a very simple DB solution for an airline company which enables flights searching, I would probably do the following:

- table_airport (id, iata_code, name)
- table_flights (id, id_departure, id_destination, date_departure)

How should I create my NOSQL tables to create the same solution?

Should I create one table per airport like below?

**table airport_nyc**

- iata_code_to (partition)
- date_departure (sort)

Comment: In the NoSQL world you'd first make a list of the queries you need to answer, because that will determine the data model.

Comment: @Maurice can you be a bit more specific? can you give an example?

Comment: @Nanofunk: Not really, I'm describing a general principle, and we need to know the access patterns before we can help OP design their table.